# Checking event on a date against database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow and Firebase database for this project. I am trying to take in a user's input for an event on a certain date, for example, "What event is there on 5th August?". However, I keep getting undefined. [Asking the question on Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPxIt.png) , [Intent for asking of the event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0tDd.png), [Firebase Database for events dates reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbaS3.png)

```
    const db = admin.database();
const action = request.body.queryResult.action;

    if (action === 'event_date') {
    const courses = request.body.queryResult.parameters.date.trim();
    const ref = db.ref(`events`);

    ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const result = snapshot.val();
        if (result === null) {
            response.json({
                fulfillmentText: `We do not have any events on this day. Please try another date!`
            });
            return;
        }
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `We have ${result.name}`,
            source: action
        });

    }).catch((err) => {
        response.json({
            fulfillmentText: `I don't know what is it`
        });

    })

} else {
    response.json({
        fulfillmentText: `I don't know what is it`
    });
}

});
```

Comment: are you getting `courses` ? have you tried to check?
is the format in DB and in 'Courses' same?

Comment: hi there, if you are looking at 'const courses', then just ignore that. I am looking at just events. Basically 'const courses' is events. Sorry for the confusion.

I am quite confused with the date format. I set the value of @sys.date as date.partial. If I am not wrong, if the user says "5th August", it will be in the format of "UUUU-08-05". As such, I have set "UUUU-08-05" in the database for the event on that date. However, I am still getting "We have undefined". 

Hope this helps to clarify!

Comment: that's it now you have to work with date both format are not same anyhow